# Limpiar parametros/Validación Backend

Tags: php, html, validación, seguridad, backend

**Resumen**

El día de hoy recibí una capacitación en 'Desarrollo Seguro' lo cual consiste en hacernos entender lo vulnerable que son las paginas web cuando no se usan validaciones tanto en el  FontEnd como en el BackEnd, cuando no usas validaciones en el BackEnd los hackers pueden sacar información valiosa de los errores que producen.

Para evitar eso  quiero compartirles a como Limpiar y validar parámetros en el BackEnd así aumentando la seguridad de tus software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="select.php" method="post">
        <label >Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="user">
        <br>     
        <br>        
        <label >Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$user= trim($_POST['user']); 
$password= trim($_POST['password']);

$user = preg_replace('/[0-9\@\*\()\_\.\;\{}\:\%" "]+/', '', $user);
//Limpiamos el parametro user, si tiene alguno de los caracteres de arriba se eliminaran
$user = filter_var($user, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//Limpiamos el parametro user si tiene alguna etiqueta HTML

echo "$user";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
// numeros enteros
if(filter_var($password, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)=== 0 || !filter_var($password, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false){
echo("Si es valido el numero entero");
}else{
    echo("NO VALIDO");
}
//Validamos el campo $password si no llega a tener un numero entero nos arroja "No Valido"

// Validar Email
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$email = "john.doe@example.com";
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("Si señor, es valido el Email");
} else {
  echo("$email No señor, No es valido Email");
}
//Validamos nuestro parametro $email si no tiene el @ nos arojara "No es valido Email"

?>
```

Aquí pueden ver la documentación/tutorial de como limpiar y validar los parametros recogidos.

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_stripslashes.asp)
[.hackmetrix](https://blog.hackmetrix.com/xss-cross-site-scripting/)

Espero les guste mi aporte

Comment: En PHP 8.1 la constante `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` está [marcada como obsoleta](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_8_1#filter_sanitize_string) y puede ser eliminada en futuras versiones.